# Display misclassified images in pytorch

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm new to pytorch and numpy so this may be a dumb question. I'd like to see some images misclassified by my net, with the correct label and the predicted label. Here is my code

```
valid_and_test_set = torchvision.datasets.MNIST("./mnist", train=False, download=True)
dataset_valid, dataset_test = torch.utils.data.random_split(valid_and_test_set,[5000, 5000])
dataset_test.dataset.transform = transform #transform is composed by unsqueeze, normalize, view and gaussian noise with randn
dataset_test.dataset.target_transform = OneHot() #OneHot return the label
dataloader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_test.dataset, batch_size=5000, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)

def test(dataset, dataloader):
    net.eval()  
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in dataloader:
            inputs = batch[0]
            inputs = inputs.to(device, non_blocking=True)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
            return predictions
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's atleast two ways you could do this in.

One is, to store the images which were misclassified during evaluation(running through the test data) and plot those. This is shown [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/viewing-misclassified-image-predictions/82410)

Another way is to make use of TensorBoard. This is quite elegant in my opinion, and you can find a comprehensive guide for it [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-dinber19-take-a-deeper-look-at-your-pytorch-model-with-the-new-tensorboard-built-in-513969cf6a72)

Answer (score 1):

```
def test(dataset, dataloader):
    net.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in dataloader:
            inputs = batch[0]
            label=batch[1]
            inputs = inputs.to(device, non_blocking=True)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
            for sampleno in range(batch[0].shape[0]):
                if(label[sampleno]!=predictions[sampleno]):
                    print("Actual Lable")
                    print(label[sampleno])
                    print("Predicted Label")
                    print(predictions[sampleno])
                    showimg(inputs[sampleno].cpu())
            return predictions
```

You can write showing() function like that

```
def showimg(model):
    model=np.reshape(model.numpy(),[28,28]) # For 1D Vector
    
    #If you normalize the image then use Next three-line
    #Otherwise skip that
    mean=np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406] )
    std=np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    model=(model*std+mean)
    


    #print(model)

    cv2.imshow("ABC", model)
    
    #waits for user to press any key
    #(this is necessary to avoid Python kernel form crashing)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #closing all open windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is "data" variable iin the train function?

Comment: Modified that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error, don't know what this means

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
    288 
    289         # test on validation
--> 290         predictions = test(dataset_valid, dataloader_valid)
    291         accuracy_valid = 100. * predictions.eq(dataset_valid.dataset.targets[dataset_valid.indices].to(device)).sum().float() / len(dataset_valid)
    292 

 in test(dataset, dataloader)
    236                     print("Predicted Label")
    237                     print(predictions[sampleno])
--> 238                     showimages(inputs[sampleno].cpu())
    239             return predictions
    240 

 in showimages(model)
    240 
    241 def showimages(model):
--> 242     model=np.transpose(model.numpy(),(1,2,0))
    243 
    244     

<__array_function__ internals> in transpose(*args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in transpose(a, axes)
    649 
    650     """
--> 651     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
    652 
    653 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     59 
     60     try:
---> 61         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     62     except TypeError:
     63         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: what's the size of your ```input ``` and ```input[sampleno]``` ?

Comment: torch.Size([5000, 784]) and torch.Size([784]). The problem is that this is grayscale and you used RGB (I think)

Comment: Ow ok, I did that for 3D array (RGB Image) but in your case input is a vector, I have modified my answer. I guess It will work this time

Comment: Almost done, I got an error for invalid shape (1, 28, 28) on plt.imshow (I had to use this because I have problems with OpenCV on Debian)

Comment: use ```np.squeeze()``` function before using ```plt.inshow```

Comment: I did it, but I get no output. I'm sorry if I'm bothering you, I just need to see the images and It's more difficult than building the model.

Comment: what do you mean by no output? error msg ? or blank image? are you normalizing the images before training and testing?

Comment: I mean nothing, no error message, no blank lines/images, absolutely nothing. I have normalized the input and denormalized before printing as you did in your example (with 1 value instead of 3)

Comment: Try opencv version. I don't use ```plt``` that much.

Comment: I forgot to plt.show() after plt.imshow, and it now it works. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: you can delete this answer and conversation. Since it's not the actual answer